# Get React DatePicker date value in onChange

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm using `react-datepicker`, and I'm unable to get the actual date in `onChange`.

This is my component :

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

const DatePick = () => {
  return (
    <DatePicker
      locale="fr"
      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
      onChange={(date) => {
        console.log(date);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default DatePick;
```

In console.log I'm getting this kind of string `Thu Dec 09 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)`.

I need to get the date as `dd-MM-yyyy` in `onChange` or a date that I can format and use later in a form and submit its value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Below code , it will work like a charm

```
const [Cdate, setDate] = useState(new Date().toLocaleDateString('fr-FR'));
return (
 <>
  <DatePicker
    dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
    value={Cdate}
    onChange={(date) => {
      const d = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('fr-FR');
      console.log(d);
      setDate(d);
    }}
  />
 </>
);
```

stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nov8it?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Date object, to format the date as you would like. For instance :

```
onChange={(date) => {
    const dateString = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString()
    console.log(dateString)
  }}
```

You will then get the date formated to your locale time zone. However, if you specified a different format in your `DatePicker` from your local timezone format, then you can specify it as a parameter for `toLocaleDateString`:

```
new Date(date).toLocaleDateString("fr-FR")
```